# Using Scroll View and Page Controller for tutorial screen

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I want to make a tutorial screen and have put a scroll view and a Page Controller.  I want to put image so that the user can swipe through the tutorial screen on first boot.  However I can put labels like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    float defWidth = _scrollView.frame.size.width;
    float defHeight = _scrollView.frame.size.height;

    _scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    _scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(defWidth * _pageControl.numberOfPages, _scrollView.frame.size.height);
    _scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    _scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    _scrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;
    _scrollView.bounces = NO;
    _scrollView.delegate = self;

    UIColor *bgColor[] = {[UIColor orangeColor],[UIColor brownColor],[UIColor grayColor],[UIColor darkGrayColor],[UIColor blackColor]};

    for (int i = 0; i < _pageControl.numberOfPages; i++) {
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        float x = (defWidth * (float)i);
        label.frame = CGRectMake(x, 0.0f, defWidth, defHeight);
        label.backgroundColor = bgColor[i];
        label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AppleGothic" size:20];
        NSLog(@"%d,%f", i, x);
        label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"hogehoge%d", (i + 1)];
        NSLog(@"%@", label.text);
        [_scrollView addSubview:label];
    }

}
```

But I cannot put images instead of labels.  How can I put images in the scroll view so that it will be a slide show of few pictures?

Answer (score 2):

to create a sliding image show so the user can swipe through the the images or images of the tutorials as you say, i find ray's tutorial very helpful. it also comes with the project sample code that has four different ways of sliding images. here is the link for that tutorial which is going to help you understand how it can be done.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content

in adition if you want to just have a slide show there is a great control done by kirualex that is a nifty control and you can download it here:

https://github.com/kirualex/KASlideShow

i could have done a run down of these methods but it would be very lengthy and i think by going through the tutorial and looking at the codes you will understand this subject much better.